# How to use Factory to create on a dynamic schema?

Tags: laravel, automated-tests

I am writing a Unit Test and need to use a dymanic schema, depending on the `$customer->name`.
Let´s see some code:

The Customer Factory:

```
public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            "name" => $this->faker->name,
            "name_image" => $this->faker->imageUrl,
            "schema" => $this->faker->name,
            "created_at" => now(),
            "updated_at" => now(),
        ];
    }
```

The test snipet:

```
Customer::factory()
            ->count(1)
            ->hasAttached($user)
            ->create();
        $schema = strtolower($user->customer[0]->schema);
        $schema = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $schema);
```

At this point I got the $schema. Now I want to use the $schema to run the next factory creating the schema and using it to create the table invites, like:

```
Invite::factory()
            ->count(10)
            ->create(
                [
                    'schema_name' => $schema,
                ]
            );
```

It is possible?

I expect that creates a table `invites` on the `$schema`

Comment: I would assume the schema would act kinda like an enum having x cases, do you know these cases and is it possible to write em conditionally like if schema = i do this if schema = j do that.

Comment: What if I use Schema::create($schema.'.invites'), func...